# How can I connect to Sharepoint server remotely via internet and upload a project

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, development, remote

Is it possible that I develop or upload a SharePoint project onto a SharePoint server via internet?

I intend to develop the project on my PC, and then upload it to the server. Should I set up a VPN among these two computers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Regarding SharePoint Designer.**

Yes, You can install and use SharePoint designer on your PC to content and customize your SharePoint site that hosted on a server in the same network or hosted over the internet.

> **Note:** the SharePoint site URL should be reachable from your PC.

---

**Regarding developing the project on your PC,**

This depends on What's the type of solution and the Object Model that you use?.

1. In case you are using `Server Side Object Model` (WSP Solutions), so you should have a development environment that has SharePoint & Visual Studio installed. Or check this workaround (**Not tried**) [Develop SharePoint Solutions without installing SharePoint on Visual Studio](http://geekswithblogs.net/KunaalKapoor/archive/2012/04/26/develop-sharepoint-solutions-without-installing-sharepoint-on-visual-studio.aspx)
2. In case, you are using `Client-Side Object Model` (SharePoint-Addins), Yes, you can by referencing the below DLL's to your solution

   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
   - Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime

> The above DLL's should be first copied from SharePoint Server at `C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\`
>   to your PC then referenced to your solution.
>
> **Note:** the SharePoint site URL should be reachable from your PC.

3. In case, you are using `JavaScript Object Model` (SharePoint-Addins), yes you can connect remotely your SharePoint site without having SharePoint installed on your PC. check also [Develop SharePoint Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/develop-sharepoint-add-ins)

> **Note:** the SharePoint site URL should be reachable from your PC.

Comment: Thank you! I am very newbie. You wrote "*In case you are using Server Side Object Model (WSP Solutions), so you should have a development environment that has SharePoint & Visual Studio installed.*"  By "SharePoint" do you mean Sharepoint server? Also can I use Windows 2016 server on virtual machine for this purpose?

Comment: Hi , Ahmed, you are welcome, yes SharePoint Server, regarding the second question, yes you can use Windows Server 2016 in case you will install SharePoint Server 2016, Note Windows Server 2016 RTM is not supported for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Sorry if I am so newbie, you didn't say in your answer; how can I transfer my files to sever?!

Comment: no problem bro, you are welcome, could you please tell me which type of your above scenarios you are working to can tell you how to do that?

Comment: I just learned from Youtube videos that I can connect to a sharepoint server (in internet) via sharepoint designer. How about the first one! suppose I have an installed sharepoint and did something to it. How it is reflected on the remote Sharepoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62416/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-ahmad).